# Странно работает или не работает связка try и except ObjectDoesNotExist в проекте Django

Tags: python, django, try

Есть функция `get_menu_tree`, внутри которой из модели `Category` по `slug` извлекается 1 запись.

Допустим, слаг указан неверно (по любой причине). Хочу, чтобы дальнейшее выполнение кода было прекращено, и отобразилась другая страница с ошибкой или выполнился редирект на произвольную страницу.

Но ничего не выходит. Код продолжает выполняться даже при том, что на лицо ошибка. Срабатывает только `raise Http404`.

```
def get_menu_tree(request, cat_slug=''):
context = create_context()

try:
    parent_node = Category.objects.get(slug=cat_slug, debug=False)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    return render(request, template_name=settings.PAGE_404, context={})

context['parent_node'] = parent_node
return context
```

Если вместо

```
return render(request, template_name=settings.PAGE_404, context={})
```

написать

```
raise Http404
```

то все ОК.

Отсюда вопрос: а почему собственно так получается?

Comment: Почему вы в одном месте возвращаете HttpResponse, а в другом какой-то context? Подозреваю, что именно в этом и загвоздка — определитесь, что конкретно вы хотите возвращать

Comment: К сожалению нет... Более того изначально этот код работал. А потом перестал. И не могу пока понять, что изменилось
Да и почему бы не делать так? 
предложите вариант как тогда по другому решить задачу перенаправить пользователя на другую страницу в случае ошибки?
Можно конечно все сделать через отображении страницы 404 и других, но хотелось бы ее кастомизировать и передать в шаблон страницы с ошибкой дополнительную информацию через тот же context

Comment: "К сожалению нет" что? Ещё раз - определитесь, что конкретно вы хотите возвращать и как конкретно и кем конкретно должно обрабатываться возвращённое вами значение